# Avoid time sychronization between OSX and XP using Parallels

Tags: macos, sync, time, parallels

I need to have my XP virtual machine system date, de-synchronized from my OSX host server.

I'm using Paralles 4 but I can't figure out what or where is the option to do that.

I already uncheck the "synchronize with time server" inside the XP box.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh!..

I've found it

Configure/Features/Services/Synchronize time with the host computer

:'(